# T-SQL Limited Cross Join

Tags: sql-server

I want to join 2 tables such that I get the `NAR` for every combination of `Type` and `BillingID` where it exists.

Where a `BillingID` doesn't have a certain `Type`, then either `NULL` or `0` is returned for the `NAR` along with the `Type` and `BillingID`.

Is something like this even possible using SQL?

A simplified version of my data is shown below:

Type list:

```
+----------+
| Type     |
+----------+
| NEW      |
| CHNG     |
| LAP      |
+----------+
```

Data:

```
+----------+-----------+-----+
| Type     | BillingID | NAR |
+----------+-----------+-----+
| NEW      | ABC       |   5 |
| CHNG     | ABC       |  15 |
| LAP      | ABC       |  10 |
| CHNG     | DEF       |  20 |
+----------+-----------+-----+
```

Desired result:

```
+----------+-----------+-----+
| Type     | BillingID | NAR |
+----------+-----------+-----+
| NEW      | ABC       |   5 |
| CHNG     | ABC       |  15 |
| LAP      | ABC       |  10 |
| CHNG     | DEF       |  20 |
| NEW      | DEF       |   0 |
| LAP      | DEF       |   0 |
+----------+-----------+-----+
```

The last 2 rows are what is causing me problems.

Comment: **SHOW US** what you've tried so far! We'll help with your efforts - but we won't just write the whole code for you .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
declare @table table (type1 varchar(5))
insert into @table
values
('new'),
('chng'),
('lap')

declare @table2 table (typeid varchar(5),billingid varchar(5),nar int)
insert into @table2
values
( 'NEW',     'ABC',   5 ),
( 'CHNG' ,   'ABC',  15 ),
( 'LAP' ,    'ABC',  10 ),
( 'CHNG' ,   'DEF',  20 )

select Z.*,case when c.nar IS null then 0 else c.nar end as nar from (
select * from @table a
 outer apply (select distinct billingid from @table2 b ) p
 )Z
 left join @table2 c on Z.type1 = c.typeid and Z.billingid = c.billingid

 order by billingid
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, the concept of ```apply``` and how to use it was the solution I needed